# Is there a way to apply a two-argument function to matrices?

Tags: matrix

Basically, I want an analog of `MatrixFunction` but such that it can apply a two-argument function to two matrices.

Comment: I’m having a hard time understand whether you want to do something `f[A,B]`, where A, B are matrices, or `f[A[i,j]]`, or something else. Can you give an example of a proposed syntax?

Comment: @CATrevillian `MatrixFunction[f[#1,#2]&,A,B]`

Comment: You can certainly define a function with that desired syntax (I'd suggest a different name to avoid collision), but it just means you still have to define how `f` operates on your matrices. Do you have an example `f` in mind?

Comment: @lericr I wand `f` being arbitrary function.

Comment: @Anixx Do the matrices A and B have the same dimensions? Do you just want a way to `MapThread` the function f over each corresponding pair of elements from the two matrices? Can you show a practical application of your idea with an actual function that takes two arguments, and two small sample matrices, and the desired output?

Comment: But you don't want an arbitrary function. You want a function that is usually defined for "simple" arguments but that has an analog for matrices. So, for example,  `MatrixFunction[Times, A, B]`. Now, `Times` is a bad example, of course, because you can do that one directly without anything like `MatrixFunction`. So, I still say that an example would be helpful. Now, if what you really want is `MapThread`, like @MarcoB suggested, then the problem is already solved.

Comment: I'm not really asserting that "you want ...". I'm inferring that since your referenced MatrixFunction that "you want ..."

Comment: My understanding of `MatrixFunction` is that for an analytic $f(x) =\sum c_n x^n$, it computes $f(A) = \sum c_n A^n$. The analog that comes to mind is, given $f(x,y)=\sum c_{ij}x^iy^j$, then compute $f(A,B)=\sum c_{ij}A^iB^j$. That seems ill-defined unless $A$ and $B$ commute. Can you give a reference where such a function is defined? Otherwise I think it's a question for a math site.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Well, I am interested in the case where they indeed commute.

Comment: What about $f$?

Comment: @MichaelE2 f should be an arbitrary function, at least to the same extent as suitable for `MatrixFunction`

Comment: If you can figure out a way to generalize [any of the definitions for a univariate matrix function](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1955.11988651) to the bi- (or even multi-) variate case, we might have something to start with.

Comment: I guess it's worth asking since there's hardly any information in the question: Aside from commuting, I don't suppose the matrices are also diagonalizable? I don't see an easy way if not. The analog of the usual idea is to reduce $f(A,B)$ to $Z\,f(C,D)\,Z^{-1}$, where $C=Z^{-1}AZ,\;D=Z^{-1}BZ$ and $f(C,D)$ is easier to compute. The convolution in the double sum seems to mess up the standard approaches, except for diagonalizable ones. As I said, it may be better to ask on a math site, where more people may be familiar with such things.

Answer (score 1):

Is the following application of `MapThread` with a level specification what you are looking for?

```
aa = Array[a, {3, 4}];
bb = Array[b, {3, 4}];

MapThread[f, {aa, bb}, 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image: the resulting matrix, made of f[a[i, j], b[i,j]] elements]

Comment: Where `MatrixFunction` is applied here?

Comment: @Anixx It is not; but it seems that this reproduces the functionality of `MatrixFunction` the way I understood your question. If this is not the case, then please add the example I requested in comments to clarify what you are after.

Comment: I do not see how this can reproduce the functionality of `MatrixFunction` without invoking it.

Comment: @Anixx You say in the first sentence of your question that you want "an analog of `MatrixFunction`". If the only answer you will take is `MatrixFunction` itself, then it either already does what you want (rendering your question moot) or it does not. In the latter case, then necessarily one will have to come up with another approach that does not involve `MatrixFunction`. It would really be easier to discuss your requirements if you could include in your question an example of input, function to be applied, and your desired output.